# socialSignup error can't signup without email

Tags: angularjs, backand

I have a problem when I try to signup to my app using Facebook, this worked until recently, the provider is 'facebook':

```
self.socialSignup = function (provider) {
    return Backand.socialSignUp(provider).then(function (response) {
        loadUserDetails();
        return response;
    });
};
```

But now I get this error:

> MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "{"error":{"message":"can't signup without email. NO_EMAIL_SOCIAL","provider":"facebook"}}...
>
> "can't signup without email. NO_EMAIL_SOCIAL (signing in with facebook)","error_description":"can't signup without email. NO_EMAIL_SOCIAL (signing in with facebook)"

I use angularbknd-sdk 1.8.2, but I try with 1.8.11.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not reproduced with Vanilla SDK 
backand-angular1-sdk 1.9.1
Install it with
bower install backand-angular1-sdk

We tried again now with backand-angular1-sdk 1.9.13 and it worked. Note **1.9.13**

Comment: I change the Backand SDK to backand-angular1-sdk v1.9.13 and i use the SDK backand-vanilla-sdk v1.1.11, but i recive the same error "can't signup without email. NO_EMAIL_SOCIAL".